# Basic question : Quotient algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could someone explain which are the elements of the quotient algebra $P(̩\omega)/fin$, here   $P(̩\omega)$  denotes the power set of $\omega$ and fin the ideal of finite subsets of $\omega$ (and I am bit confused by the definition of quotient algebra in Jech).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please tell us a bit more about the context of this question?

Comment: The *quotient algebra* $B/I$ where $B$ is a *boolean algebra* and $I$ is an *ideal* on $B$ is defined at page 80.

Comment: The *power set* of a set whatever is a boolean algebra wrt to usual set operations; see [Algebra of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets).

Comment: You have to check that $\text {fin}$ is an [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(set_theory)) on $\mathscr P (\omega)$.

Comment: You have to try to understand what does it mean to "quotient" the structure $\mathscr {P}(\omega)$... Basically (see page 80) the starting point is the def of the equiv relation: two elements of $\mathscr {P}(\omega)$, i.e. two subsets of $\omega$, are equiv iff their symmetric diff belongs to $\text {fin}$, i.e. iff the symm didd is a *finite* set.

Comment: The second key-point is that the quotient structure, i.e. the new structure whose elements are the equivalence classes defined according to the equiv rel above, is homomorphic to the "original" set: in this case $\mathscr {P}(\omega)$.